# Colorbox Youtube Video Autoplay In Mobile Device

Tags: jquery, colorbox, youtube-javascript-api

I am working with colorbox for popup a youtube video when click. As i need to autoplay of the video when click. My code works well in laptop. However it doesn't work in smart phone. Autoplay is not happening.It need to click the video to play.

I have tried many way to force play. But i couldn't get success. How i have tried here is a demo.

Please if there is any solution of this problem to force play for mobile device, would you please help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script>        
                var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);    

                var player;
                function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                  player = new YT.Player('player1', {
                    events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady
                    }
                  });
                }

                function onPlayerReady(event) {


                          player.playVideo();     
                }   

        $("document").ready(function(){

         $("#content a[href*='youtube.com']").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var href = $this.attr('href');
            var youtubeId = href.split('/').pop();
            var link_id=$this.attr('id');
            $this.colorbox({ html: function() {
            var iframe = '<iframe id="player1" width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId + '?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>';
            var output = "<div style='line-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;'>" + iframe + '</div>';
            return output;
            },
            onComplete:function(){
            //  player.playVideo();
             }
            });
        });             
    });

</script>

<div id="content">
<p><a id="aaa" class='youtube' href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok">To see video click here</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's ```$( document ).ready()```, not ```$("document").ready()```. Also, ```onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()``` is not called anywhere.

Comment: onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() has been called at the top of the code .

Comment: In the code you provided there's only one occurrence of ```onYouTubePlayerAPIReady``` and it's the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  put this code at the bottom because on load it this will call api ready function.

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```